# Object disappears when fabricJs canvas width and height is more than 4096px in chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm using fabricJs to add images to the canvas, And i'm changing the canvas width and height with `canvas.setWidth(width,{backstoreOnly:true})` and `canvas.setHeight(height,{backstoreOnly:true})`, but when canvas width or height are more than `4096px`, all object disappears in chrome, i tested it in Firefox everything works fine i can add width up to `10000px` or more, but in chrome i can't add more than `4096px`

does anyone know why it's working on Firefox but not chrome and how to fix it, because i searched a lot and didn't find any good solutions.

i don't know if this will help:

fabricjs version `4.4.0`

chrome version `90.0.4430.93`

Firefox version `78.10.0esr`